# Dynamic nested routing in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, ngroute

Trying to implement the following route system with angular stateProvider:
***some_domain.com/abc/pqr/xyz***

Issue is the number of levels after "some_domain.com" can vary. It can be like

- some_domain.com/abc/pqr/xyz
- some_domain.com/abc/pqr
- some_domain.com/abc
- some_domain.com/abc/pqr/xyz/1234

tried the many approaches for this in the state definition:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dummy', {
        url: '/*',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'LandingPage'
    });
}]);
```

Can anybody help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the parameters you are talking about are part of the route itself, so you cannot have a single route to handle all these cases. I can think of 2 ways to go about it :

1. Create a seperate route for each case.
2. Use optional parameters if you can modify the logic accordingly. If the parameters can be optional, they should sent as query parameters instead of making them part of URL as such. So, the URL becomes something like :

   ```
   url: '/dummy?param1?param2?param3'
   ```